# Change toolbar action item background color

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-styles, android-menu

How can I change a menu action item background color in a toolbar?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:edo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/my_action"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:title="@string/title"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Then in my activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_actions, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_action);

    MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

This is not working, because getActionView always returns null.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```
public void changeActionMenuItemsBackground(int color) {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View v = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ActionMenuView) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it right in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or later

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    changeActionMenuItemsBackground(Color.BLACK);
    return true;
}
```

I hope, it helps

Answer (score 0):

getActionView() is working when there's a custom actionView from setActionView() in my case.

Create a layout and set it as action view to your menu item like this:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.new_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_action);
    View myView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_item_layout, null);
    ((ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit)).setOnClickListener(this);
    item = MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, myView);
    MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue));
    return true;
}
```

menu_item_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/red"
android:minHeight="0dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:src="@drawable/img_edt" />
```

Like this you can set color either in getActionView(item).setBackgroundColor(..) or in menu_item_layout.xml file itself.